# QPainterPath text renders wrong when printing

Tags: c++, qt, text, printing, qpainterpath

With Qt 5.4.2, I'm using a `QPainterPath` to render text, since the text may be split into characters and each character rendered along a curve.  I see different results across platforms and when I print.  To render the text, I've tried using `QPainter`'s `drawPath()` and `drawPolygon()` methods.

OS X 10.11.6:

- `drawPath`:  top line in Indic text has gaps that should not be there, both in a `QGraphicsView` and when I print.
- `drawPolygon`: the top line is solid as it should be, both in a `QGraphicsView` and when I print.  However, when printed, I get lots of extra fine lines between various random points in the text.

Window 7:

- `drawPath`:  same as on the Mac:  there are gaps in top line, both the `QGraphicsView` and when I print.
- `drawPolygon`:  the `QGraphicsView` is correct (no gaps), but printing still has the gaps in the top line, though it does not have the extra fine lines as when printed on the Mac.  So printing with `drawPolygon` produces identical incorrect output as printing with `drawPath`.

[Here's](https://db.tt/IlOkrZqm) a sample app that demonstrates these issues. Here's the paint code from my `QGraphicsItem` subclass in my sample app:

```
void MapGraphicsTextElement::paint(QPainter *painter,
                                   const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * /*option*/,
                                   QWidget * /*widget*/) {

  painter->setFont(font_);
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
  painter->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::black)));
  painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);

  QPainterPath path;
  path.addText(0, 0, font_, text_);

  if (fix_gaps_) {
    QPolygonF poly = path.toFillPolygon();
    painter->drawPolygon(poly, Qt::WindingFill);
  } else {
    painter->drawPath(path);
  }
}
```

Here's the code from the sample app that creates the scene and adds two of my `QGraphicsItem` subclass objects to the scene:

```
QGraphicsScene * PrintsLines::CreateScene()
{
  QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 500, 500, this);

  QScopedPointer<MapGraphicsTextElement> item(new MapGraphicsTextElement());

  item->SetText("My test text here.");
  item->SetFixGaps(fix_gaps_->isChecked());
  QFont item_font("Arial");
  item_font.setPixelSize(12);
  item->SetFont(item_font);
  item->setPos(128, 115);
  scene->addItem(item.take());

  QScopedPointer<MapGraphicsTextElement> item2(new MapGraphicsTextElement());

  item2->SetText("मेदितेरेनियन सि");
  item2->SetFixGaps(fix_gaps_->isChecked());
  QFont item_font2("Arial");
  item_font2.setPixelSize(48);
  item2->SetFont(item_font2);
  item2->setPos(128, 215);
  scene->addItem(item2.take());

  return scene;
}
```

How can I make what is rendered in a `QGraphicsView` and is printed are identical and correct?  If different solutions are required for OS X and Windows, that's ok.  Or if a newer version of Qt is required to solve this, I could upgrade Qt.

UPDATE:

As Kuba Ober suggested, I have demonstrated the printing bugs with this simple app below. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QtGui/QPainter>
#include <QtGui/QPainterPath>
#include <QtGui/QFont>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrintDialog>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinter>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  QPrinter *printer = new QPrinter();
  QPrintDialog dialog(printer);
  if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    QFont font("Arial");
    font.setPointSize(48);

    QPainter painter(printer);
    painter.setFont(font);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::black)));
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);

    // drawPath()
    QPainterPath path_drawPath;
    path_drawPath.addText(100, 200, font, "मेदितेरेनियन सि");
    painter.drawPath(path_drawPath);

    // drawPolygon()
    QPainterPath path_drawPoly;
    path_drawPoly.addText(100, 300, font, "मेदितेरेनियन सि");
    QPolygonF poly = path_drawPoly.toFillPolygon();
    painter.drawPolygon(poly, Qt::WindingFill);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any behavior that varies between platforms is a Qt bug as on both platforms all the on-screen rendering is done by the raster platform and the results should be pixel-identical as long as same fonts are used.

Comment: The on-screen rendering is identical on both platforms, but the printing errors are different.

Comment: Instead of using the graphics scene, minimize the code to a single `main()` with `QPainter`. If the problem persists, it's likely a genuine print paint engine bug.

Comment: I'm experimenting with `painter.drawText()` as a work-around.  So far, looks like I can solve this for both platforms by using `drawText()` to print and create pdf's, and use `painter.drawPolygon()` for on-screen rendering.  I guess for my curved texts I'll have to call `drawText()` separately for each character...and hope there's noticeable performance hit.

Comment: I mean "hope there's NO noticeable performance hit."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`painter.drawText()` is working for printing and for creating pdf's.  `painter.drawPolygon()` is working for on-screen rendering and outputting raster images (png & jpg).  This workaround appears to be sufficient to solve my problem.